# Filtering reports through Apex and Visualforce (Salesforce web)

Tags: java, html, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am trying to print out a Salesforce custom object database and have a filter. The filters work correctly, but the "All" filter does not show the full table as a default or when I click "All" from another filter. How can I do this?

Here is the relevant Apex code:

```
public string itemPickValue{get; set;}
    public List<QC_Issue__c> issuesList{get; set;}
    public List<QC_Issue__c> results; 

    public List<QC_Issue__c> getIssues() {
        results = Database.query(
            'SELECT Component_Category__c, Issue_Name__c, Issue_Description__c, Severity_1_Criteria__c, Severity_2_Criteria__c, Severity_3_Criteria__c, File__c FROM QC_Issue__c Order By Component_Category__c, Issue_Name__c'

        );

        return results; 
    }

    public void getIssuesList() {
        if(itemPickValue.equals('All')) issuesList = Database.query('SELECT Component_Category__c, Issue_Name__c, Issue_Description__c, Severity_1_Criteria__c, Severity_2_Criteria__c, Severity_3_Criteria__c, File__c FROM QC_Issue__c');
        issuesList = Database.query('SELECT Component_Category__c, Issue_Name__c, Issue_Description__c, Severity_1_Criteria__c, Severity_2_Criteria__c, Severity_3_Criteria__c, File__c FROM QC_Issue__c WHERE Component_Category__c =: itemPickValue');
    }
```

And here is the relevant Visualforce code:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="QC Glossary" id="qc_issues_list">
                <h3>Filter by Component Category:</h3>
                <br></br>
                <!-->Start Filter and List<-->
                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!itemPickValue}">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getIssuesList}" rerender="table"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="All" itemValue="All"></apex:selectOption>
                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Animation/VFX" itemValue="Animation/VFX"></apex:selectOption>
                    </apex:selectList>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>

                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="table" value="{!issuesList}" var="qc" columnsWidth="10%, 5%, 50%, 10%, 10%, 10%, 10%">
                        <apex:column value="{!qc.Component_Category__c }"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!qc.Issue_Name__c }"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!qc.Issue_Description__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!qc.Severity_1_Criteria__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!qc.Severity_2_Criteria__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!qc.Severity_3_Criteria__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!qc.File__c}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the following changes

- Removed Code duplication, using the getIssues method rather than duplicating the SOQL statement.
- Added an if/else clause; Your main issue was in the `getIssuesList` you had an if statement that if true would store the full result in `issuesList`and then immediatly overwrite it in the next line with a filtered list attempting to use the category name 'All'

There are various other things to point out here; but I'll leave that for now.

The result:

```
public String itemPickValue{get; set;}
public List<QC_Issue__c> issuesList{get; set;}
public List<QC_Issue__c> results; 

public List<QC_Issue__c> getIssues() {
    results = Database.query(
        'SELECT Component_Category__c, Issue_Name__c, Issue_Description__c, Severity_1_Criteria__c, Severity_2_Criteria__c, Severity_3_Criteria__c, File__c FROM QC_Issue__c Order By Component_Category__c, Issue_Name__c'
    );

    return results; 
}

public void getIssuesList() {
    if(itemPickValue.equals('All')) {
        issuesList = getIssues();
    } else {
        issuesList = Database.query('SELECT Component_Category__c, Issue_Name__c, Issue_Description__c, Severity_1_Criteria__c, Severity_2_Criteria__c, Severity_3_Criteria__c, File__c FROM QC_Issue__c WHERE Component_Category__c =: itemPickValue');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. One more question--how can I ensure that upon opening the web page, the results of "All" are immediately displayed? It only works once I have clicked into a new filter and switched back to "All." Would it need to set it as a default value somehow?

Comment: In the Constructor to your page controller set the itemPickValue to the default 'All' Value, and execute the getIssuesList method to set the issueList value.